# Font-face in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, font-face

I know that these questions are very often asked, but I wanna know what is wrong with my code.

When I try to load the font, IE wont display the font.

Here is my code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: CalistoMTItalic;
    src: url('../fonts/CALISTI.oet'); 
    src: url('../fonts/CALISTI.oet?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/CALISTI.TTF') format('truetype');
}
```

Does anybody know the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes include:

- mistyping file name extension .eot as .oet
- using just EOT and TTF formats
- not contacting Microsoft regarding legal use of [their font](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=87)

Answer (score 0):

The correct extension is eot, not oet.

Also, make sure the path to the font files is relative to the url of the css file.

If that doesn't fix your issue then please see related topics on StackOverflow - I see at least 4 with an almost identical title in the "Related" column on the right-hand side of this question.

Comment: Wow really thanks! The extension was my mistake, I looked at all of the topics but this was something which I didn't spot. It works fine